# When $\cap f^i(R)=k$? where $f:R \to R$ is a $k$-algebra endomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $R$ be a (commutative) $k$-algebra, and $f$ a $k$-algebra endomorphism of $R$.

> What can be said about $I:=\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} f^i(R)$? Is it possible to determine when $I=k$?

**Remarks:**

**(i)** Of course, if $f$ happens to be surjective, then $I=R$.

**(ii)** We will require that the dimension of $R$ as a $k$-vector space is infinite. (If $\dim_k(R) = n < \infty$, then from $\dim_k(R) \geq \dim_k(f(R)) \geq \dim_k(f^2(R)) \ldots$ and [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there exist $i<j$ such that $\dim_k(f^i(R))=\dim_k(f^j(R)) \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then, since $f^j(R) \subseteq f^i(R)$, we get that $f^j(R) = f^i(R)$, etc.).

**Special cases:** I guess that my question is too general, so I do not mind to concentrate on $R=k[t]$ or $R=k[x,y]$, though I prefer a more general $R$, for example, a Noetherian ring.

A somewhat relevant question is [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296279/must-a-counterexample-f-to-the-n-dimensional-jc-satisfy-cap-fikx-1-ldo).

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathfrak{I}^i$? Is it the set $a_1\cdots a_i$ with $a_p\in\mathfrak{I}$ for $1\leq p\leq i$?

Comment: Good comment! Thank you. I have written $\cap f(R)^i$ (the definition is as you mentioned), but I actually meant to write $\cap f^i(R)$... I will soon fix this in my question.

Comment: Consider $f(R)^i$. Clearly, for $i >1$, $f(R)^i=f(R^i)$ and $f(R) = f(R^2) = f(R^3) \ldots$, so $\cap_{i \geq 1} f(R)^i=\cap_{i \geq 1} f(R)= f(R)$ and $\cap_{i \geq 0} f^i(R)= f(R) \cap R=f(R)$.