# Descending chain of algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, let $R$ be a (commutative) $k$-algebra with $1$, and $\{R_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ (with $R_0:=R$) a descending chain of $k$-subalgebras of $R$, namely $R \supseteq R_1 \supseteq R_2 \supseteq \ldots$, with $R_i \neq k$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Assume that $R$ has finite [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension), $\dim(R)=n < \infty$.

Further assume that $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} R_i=k$.

> Does it follow that there exist indices $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ such that
>   $\dim(R_{i_j})=j$, $1 \leq j \leq n$?

Of course, we can take $i_n=0$; indeed, $R_{i_n}=R_0=R$ is of Krull dimension $n$.

**Example:** $R=k[x,y]$, $R_1=k[y]$, $R_2=k[y^2]$, $R_3=k[y^4]$, $R_4=k[y^8]$, so $R_m=k[y^{2^{m-1}}]$, $m \geq 1$.
$\dim(R)=2$, $\dim(R_m)=1$, $m \geq 1$. (How to prove that $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} R_i=k$?). But this is just an example. Perhaps there exists a counterexample to my question?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** After receiving a counterexample in the comments, I wish to restrict my question to the special case where $\dim(R)=2$ (or even to $R=k[x,y]$).
In other words:

> If $R=k[x,y]$, $R \supseteq R_1 \supseteq R_2 \supseteq \ldots$,
>   with $\dim(R_i) \in \{1,2\}$ (this guarantees that $R_i \neq k$) and $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}R_i =k$, does it follow that there exists $l \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $\dim(R_l)=1$? (If there exists such $l$, then for every $L > l$, we also have $\dim(R_L)=1$).

I think that a counterexample is $R_1=k[x^2,y^2]$, $R_2=k[x^4,y^4]$, $R_3=k[x^8,y^8]$, etc. Here, $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}R_i=k$ and $\dim(R_i)=2$, for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore, I wish to further restrict my question to $R_i$, $i \geq 1$, of the following special forms:

> $R_i=k[f_i,g_i]$, where the Jacobian of $f_i$ and $g_i$ is a non-zero scalar, namely, $Jac(f_i,g_i) \in k^{\times}$.

Notice that above we had $Jac(f_i,g_i)=Jac(x^{2^i},y^{2^i}) \in k[x,y]-k$,
which is not a non-zero scalar; it is just a non-zero polynomial.

Comment: What if you take $R_{i} = k$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So I should have required that $R_i \neq k$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$; I will add this.

Comment: No, it is not necessarily true. Consider $k[x,y,z] \supset k[z] \supset k[z^2] \supset k[z^3]\supset \cdots$. There's no entry with dimension 2 here.

Comment: Nice! thanks. But what if we take $R$ of Krull dimension $2$, for example $R=k[x,y]$? (a minor remark: in your counterexample I guess you meant $\ldots \supset k[z^2] \supset k[z^4] \ldots$).

Comment: Again, not true. Just take $R_i$ to be the subalgebra generated by all degree $2^i$ monomials in $k[x,y]$. Why are you interested in this result?

Comment: Yes, I have already noticed that my second question also has a counterexample, as I have added later (you probably have not yet read my later edits; this is ok of course). I am interested in this result because of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913734/when-cap-fir-k-where-fr-to-r-is-a-k-algebra-endomorphism https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296279/must-a-counterexample-f-to-the-n-dimensional-jc-satisfy-cap-fikx-1-ldo

Comment: If there is no counterexample to my third question (namely, for $R=k[x,y]$, there exist no descending chain $R_i=k[f_i,g_i]$ with $Jac(f_i,g_i) \in k^{\times}$ and $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} R_i=k$), then the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture would have a positive answer..

Comment: This follows quite immediately from: "Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
If $f:k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ has an invertible Jacobian and is not an automorphism, then $\cap f^i(k[x,y])=k$; see the paper of [V. Shpilrain and J.-T. Yu][1]." (I have quoted from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296279/must-a-counterexample-f-to-the-n-dimensional-jc-satisfy-cap-fikx-1-ldo).

Comment: This approach will probably not go anywhere, or if it does, there are likely problems with your interpretation that it would prove the two-dimensional Jacobian conjecture. This conjecture is _hard_ and _old_, which makes it likely that it would not be soluble using such elementary tools - if it were, someone would have done it by now.