# A descending chain of algebras $R_i \subseteq k[x,y]$ of Krull dimensions $2$, such that $\cap R_i$ is of Krull dimension $1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $R_i$ be a descending chain of $k$-subalgebras of $R_0:=k[x,y]$.
Assume that the [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) of each $R_i$ is $2$.

> I am looking for an example of such $R_i$'s such that, in addition, $\cap R_i$ is of Krull dimension exactly $1$.

Please see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914547/descending-chain-of-algebras?noredirect=1#comment6021413_2914547);
notice that $R_1=k[x^2,y^2]$, $R_2=k[x^4,y^4]$, $R_3=k[x^8,y^8]$, namely,
$R_i=k[x^{2^i},y^{2^i}]$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, is not an answer to my current question, since $\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}k[x^{2^i},y^{2^i}]=k$, which is of Krull dimension $0$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about $R_{i} = k[x^{2^{i}},y]$?

Comment: Thank you very much; I should have noticed that. (You can write it as an answer, if you like),